# White Space in Drawer - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using drawer widget...

But there's a white space in the container to the right side...

[image]

And here's my code...

**home.dart**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Dashboard'),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 11, 102),
      ),
      drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Home'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**custom_drawer.dart**

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _drawerItems({String? text, IconData? icon, String? route}) {
      return ListTile(
        leading: icon == null ? null : Icon(icon),
        title: Text(text!),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(route!, (route) => false);
        },
      );
    }

    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Drawer Header
          Container(
            height: 150,
            color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 11, 102),
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Welcome',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: [
                // Home
                _drawerItems(
                  text: 'Home',
                  icon: Icons.home_outlined,
                  route: homeScreenRoute,
                ),
                ExpansionTile(
                  title: const Text('Products'),
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.production_quantity_limits),
                  children: [
                    // All Products
                    _drawerItems(
                      text: 'All Products',
                      route: productScreenRoute,
                    ),
                    // Add Products
                    _drawerItems(
                      text: 'Add Products',
                      route: addProductScreenRoute,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

It also sometimes blinking when I am dragging it to left or right...

I'm using my phone (Redmi Note 7) to debug.

So, is this a problem with that?

Or am I using drawer widget in the wrong way?

Comment: On android emulator is working fine

Comment: We're encountering the same issue right now. It doesn't seem to affect all devices, because we're unable to reproduce it, but some clients are reporting this bug. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I've run your code and it works like a charm.

**It works well on my phone too ( Redmi K30 4G ).**

Here's what it looks like on my phone.

[image]

Also, your code is correct and I see nothing wrong with it. May be your phone has a problem.

Here's your output on **emulator**.

[image]

Can you release your app and test it on Redmi Note 7 to see if it's working?

For release mode, run `flutter build apk` and copy apk from `$project_directory\build\app\outputs\app-release.apk`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try it. I think the problem is in my phone or whatever. I try to release apk and see what's the output. Thank you!

Comment: Even if it's still the same, don't worry. There's nothing wrong with your code so it should work well on other devices. Cheers 

Answer (score 1):

Although it's working fine for me too, Just try adding this, maybe it can fix it!

```
    Container(
        width: double.maxFinite, // this line
        height: 150,
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 11, 102),
        child: const Center(
          child: Text(
            'Welcome',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: It's still the same. Thank you!